# testing link_to output in rails helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, minitest, helper

I have been working on my rails tests the past few days and have hit a snag with a helper test. I get the following error:

```
ActionController::UrlGenerationError: No route matches {:action=>"index", :direction=>"asc", :sort=>"publish_date"}
    app/helpers/main_pages_helper.rb:14:in `sortable'
    test/helpers/main_pages_helper_test.rb:24:in `block in <class:MainPagesHelperTest>'
```

The helper is based on the [#228 railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns), heres the main_pages_helper.rb code:

```
module MainPagesHelper

  def sortable(column, title = nil)
        direction = (column == params[:sort] && params[:direction] == "asc") ? 
            "desc" : "asc"

            # check if sort parameter is being used
            if params[:sort] == column
                title += direction == "asc" ? " ▾" : " ▴"
            end

            link_to title, :sort => column, :direction => direction
  end

        # Not yet tested
        def categorizable(category)

            category_select = params[:cat_sort] == category ? 
            params[:cat_sort] = nil : category

            link_to category, :cat_sort => category_select, 
            :sort => params[:sort], :direction => params[:direction]
        end
end
```

And this is the main_pages_helper_test.rb code:

```
require 'test_helper'

class MainPagesHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase
include MainPagesHelper

    test "should sort time descending" do
      assert_equal(sortable("publish_date", "proj_list"), 
                  (link_to "proj_list", :sort => "publish_date",
                   :direction => "desc"))
    end 

end
```

Should I not be using assert_equal as a test method? Should I even use ActionView::TestCase to test the helper?

Comment: You're using the wrong arguments for `link_to`. You should be using something like `link_to "Link text", project_list_path(sort: "publish_date", direction: "desc")`

Comment: While you can use an hash instead of a string or model instance you have to provide the controller and action. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to